# Github not serving content

Tags: github

I have built a simple repo to serve HTML content from my Github, however its throwing 404 for every page. Although the page exists.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem, here is the url:

http://madhur.github.com

It should serve this file, which exists:

https://github.com/madhur/madhur.github.com/blob/master/index.html

Comment: When did you set it up? Says it takes 10 minutes.

Comment: I set it up long ago, but recently pushed a commit. Its been quite long. Will it take 10 minutes even though its not piped through jekyll (.nojekyll) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it myself and succeeded: http://tylerlong.github.com/. I think you should put a file named "index.html" in the root folder of your repository.

I saw there was a file named "index.markdown" in your repository. Maybe github pages does not support "*.markdown" files yet.

Edit: I mean in this page: https://github.com/madhur/madhur.github.com  there is only a file named "index.markdown".

**Final Edit**:
pages are NOT served from master branch, and pages are NOT served from source branch or any other branches either. pages are served from the DEFAULT branch. Every time you push to the default branch, github will rebuild your pages. github will NOT rebuild pages if you push to branches other than the default branch. Your can make any of your branches as the default branch in the "Repository Administration" page.
I made my source branch as the default branch and pushed to it, then my home pages show contents form my source branch: http://tylerlong.github.com.

Comment: index.markdown is in "source" branch, Pages are served from "master" branch .. which has index.html.

Comment: Now that makes sense, that helps, I thought it always serves from the master branch .. thanks for correction ...